# xpath how to skip a node

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

```
<article class='article-contents'>
<div class='summary'>xxxx</div>
<p>xxxxxx</p>
<table>...</table>
<p>....</p>...
</article>
```

I have a html structure like above, i'd like to skip pass `<div class='summary'>` and get the whole content inside article section using Xpath structure.

Comment: what did you try so far? what do you mean by "get the whole content"? text content? elements in `aticle` after `<div class='summary'>`?

Comment: To get elements after `<div class='summary'>` in `<article class='article-contents'>`, you can use `//article[@class="article-contnets"]/div[@class="summary"]/following-sibling::*`

Comment: thanks paul, it works for me following-sibling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a query like this:

```
//article[@class='article-contents']/node()[not(local-name()='div' and @class='summary')]
```

This should select all child nodes of the article excluding the summary div.